# Does GTK 2/3 support efficient virtual tables?

Tags: java, gtk, virtual, gtk3, gtk2

We are developing a Java application using SWT which offers *virtual* tables. Test code which allows to switch the number of table rows between 100 and 10M works in less than 100ms on Windows and OSX, but takes several seconds on Ubuntu 16.04. Now we are wondering whether this is a shortcoming of SWT's GTK implementation or of GTK itself? In the latter case, is there a difference between GTK 2 and GTK 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** Unfortunately, GTK's [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) doesn't seem to support virtual mode at all, and it's implemented in a way that is very inefficient for large number of items. SWT chose to implement `Table` using `GtkTreeView` and introduced further problems with performance.

**SWT Table.setItemCount()**

Source for `Table.setItemCount()`:

- Repository: `http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git`
- Source file: `eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\Eclipse SWT\gtk\org\eclipse\swt\widgets\Table.java`
- Find: `public void setItemCount (int count) {`

You will see that even in `VIRTUAL` mode, `setItemCount` will allocate all items, one at a time, using `OS.gtk_list_store_append()` :

```
for (int i=itemCount; i<count; i++) {
    OS.gtk_list_store_append (modelHandle, iter);
}
```

**SWT OS.gtk_list_store_append**

Source for `OS.gtk_list_store_append` :

- Repository: `http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git`
- Source file: `eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\Eclipse SWT\gtk\org\eclipse\swt\widgets\Table.java`
- Find: `public static final void gtk_list_store_append(long /*int*/ list_store, long /*int*/ iter) {`

Here, for every item a lock is acquired and released and native method is called. I guess they should have allocated all items with a single native call, at least.

```
public static final void gtk_list_store_append(long /*int*/ list_store, long /*int*/ iter) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        _gtk_list_store_append(list_store, iter);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**GTK gtk_list_store_append**

- Repository: `git://git.gnome.org/gtk+`
- Source file: `gtk/gtkliststore.c`
- Find: `gtk_list_store_append (GtkListStore *list_store,`

It merely calls `gtk_list_store_insert(list_store, iter, -1)`

**GTK gtk_list_store_insert**

- Repository: `git://git.gnome.org/gtk+`
- Source file: `gtk/gtkliststore.c`
- Find: `gtk_list_store_insert (GtkListStore *list_store,`

The key action is `g_sequence_insert_before` that inserts into a [gsequence](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Sequences.html), which is a balanced tree.

```
void
gtk_list_store_insert (GtkListStore *list_store,
               GtkTreeIter  *iter,
               gint          position)
{
  GtkListStorePrivate *priv;
  GtkTreePath *path;
  GSequence *seq;
  GSequenceIter *ptr;
  gint length;

  g_return_if_fail (GTK_IS_LIST_STORE (list_store));
  g_return_if_fail (iter != NULL);

  priv = list_store->priv;

  priv->columns_dirty = TRUE;

  seq = priv->seq;

  length = g_sequence_get_length (seq);
  if (position > length || position < 0)
    position = length;

  ptr = g_sequence_get_iter_at_pos (seq, position);
  ptr = g_sequence_insert_before (ptr, NULL);

  iter->stamp = priv->stamp;
  iter->user_data = ptr;

  g_assert (iter_is_valid (iter, list_store));

  priv->length++;

  path = gtk_tree_path_new ();
  gtk_tree_path_append_index (path, position);
  gtk_tree_model_row_inserted (GTK_TREE_MODEL (list_store), path, iter);
  gtk_tree_path_free (path);
}
```

Unfortunately, this function does *a lot* of things that are not necessary during a bulk insert, for example it calculates the length of sequence (which has nontrivial time complexity) each time, converts indices to iterators, fires update notifications for the tree, etc etc.

I searched, but didn't find anything for bulk inserts.

**Windows implementation**

Windows implementation of `Table` uses OS-provided `ListView` control, which is efficiently implemented for virtual mode (see `LVS_OWNERDATA`)

See also: [Eclipse Bug 236863](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236863)